# phpMyAdmin access denied error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I type "localhost/phpmyadmin" in my browser, I get the following errors instead of the login page:

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

What's causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What unclear is in message you are seeing. Have you tried reading it?

Comment: just google it first. just config issue in config.inc.php  file nothing else

Comment: I was facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when hosting a website in XAMPP server and the steps I followed to resolve this issue is mentioned below:

First I locate the MySQL bin directory and then tried to log in with NULL password, It confirms that MySQL database is not accessible with NULL password

Second, I tried to log in with the password I configured for root account while installing the database. In my case, I have an only root account and didn't configure any other account in MySQL database. If you have any, try to log in with appropriate account details

Once I confirm for the working root account password, I updated MySQLHandler.php file located inside directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\websiste-folder\classes\" and updated password in the mentioned file

Cleared cache and cookies data, restarted web service the then it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the port it will work fine. Steps to change the Port.

1.Right click the WAMP icon.
2.Chose Tool 
3.Change the port in Port used by MySql Section